# Unable to find classes from Android module created from .jar file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, module

I have an app named 'fibonacci' and a jar file created from swagger-codegen called swagger-java-client-1.0.0 (build within Android studio in a separate project).

The swagger-client is brought in as a module following the instructions at the link below.
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Structure looks like this:
[image]

The dependencies section for the app is:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation project(path: ':swagger-java-client-1.0.0')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

The top-level settings.gradle is this:

```
include ':app', ':swagger-java-client-1.0.0'
rootProject.name = "Fibonacci"
```

The build.gradle for the swagger module is this:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('swagger-java-client-1.0.0.jar'))
```

When I get to the code that tries to reach the client, the app crashes because the classes (e.g. ApiClient) aren't found.

```
    ApiClient defaultClient = new ApiClient();  
    OAuth strava_oauth = (OAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("strava_oauth");
    strava_oauth.setAccessToken(access_token);

    // try to get some activities here
    ActivitiesApi apiInstance = new ActivitiesApi();
    List<SummaryActivity> result =
            apiInstance.getLoggedInAthleteActivities( 1609522135,
                    1546363735,
                    1,
                    30);
```

I've been looking but I can't find anything that describes how to have the classes in the jar file compile with the rest of the project, which I assume is the problem.  The app compiles and deploys just fine, the error occurs at run-time.

Comment: Arrrgh.  Now I'm going to get down-voted.  I already discovered part of the problem.  The swagger-codegen jar file is supposed to include the compiled output, not just source.  This is ultimately the issue I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the jar file 'swagger-java-client-1.0.0.jar' only contained sources.  This is what was generated automatically by the gradle build and I didn't question it at first.  I was able to generate a jar with the .class files instead from the command line using:

```
jar cvf swagger-java-client-1.0.0.jar *
```

from the generated/java/build/classes/java/main folder.  Once I imported this as a module, not only the did the compile work, but the swagger-generated classes were also found at runtime.